# Add background colour to text column in Quarto

Tags: css, r, quarto, reveal.js

I'm creating some slides using Quarto and the revealjs format. There is some analysis text in the left-hand side column which I'd like to have a background colour. The background box should extend to a set length rather than finish where the text ends. The right-hand side column will have an image. I'm currently working with the below but am not sure what needs including to add the background colour.

Code:

```
## Title

:::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="30%"}

* Point 1
* Point 2
* Point 3

:::
::: {.column width="70%"}

Image will go here

:::
::::
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of what the code produces]

The kind of thing I'm aiming for:

[image: Intended output of background colour behind the text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a css class (suppose `text-col`) and define `height` and `background-color` for this class and then apply the class selector `.text-col` on the `.column` Div you want.

**styles.css**

```css
.text-col {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

padding-left is only needed if you want to move the bullet points in from the edge of the box

box-sizing is only needed if padding is added and to prevent text spilling out the other side

**presentation.qmd**

```markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
css: styles.css
---

## Title

:::: {.columns}
::: {.column .text-col width="30%"}

* Point 1
* Point 2
* Point 3

:::
::: {.column width="70%"}

Image will go here

:::
::::
```

---

[image: rendered output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not that familiar with CSS, where would I define the CSS class?

Comment: @lisboakotor, define the css class in a file `styles.css` and keep that `styles.css` file in the same directory (or folder) as the qmd file. And just refer to that `styles.css` file using `css` yaml option in the qmd file.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not familiar with CSS you can use the below pattern as one way to do it and nest multiple css arguments in a row with the same div.

```
## Title

::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="30%"}
:::: {style="background-color: #2780e3"}

* Point 1
* Point 2
* Point 3

::::
:::

::: {.column width="70%"}


Image will go here

:::
:::::
```